# Matching arbitrary number of following tokens in stream using functional style

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, elixir

The problem is as follows:

1. there is a file with tokens - each token is in a separate line accompanied by some meta-data (e.g. document id),
2. some sequences of the tokens should be counted, a sequence might be one or more tokens,
3. the sequence are kept in a trie, but this is not a requirement,
4. the implementation has to be very efficient, since the file to be processed has gigabytes of data.

My present implementation (in Ruby) is as follows:

```
def convert_tuple(tuple)
  document_id, token_index, space, token = *tuple
  token = token.chomp
  token.force_encoding("ascii-8bit")
  document_id = document_id.to_i
  [document_id, token_index, space, token]
end

def count_and_match_tokens(string, index, counts, document_id, first_token_index, last_token_index)
  token_id = index[string]
  if token_id
    STDERR.puts "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % [document_id, first_token_index, last_token_index, string]
    counts[string] += 1
  end
  index.search(string).size > 0
end

counts = Hash.new(0)
index = Melisa::IntTrie.new
index.load(index_path)

CSV.open(input_path, col_sep: "\t") do |input|
  input.each do |tuple|
    document_id, first_token_index, space, token = convert_tuple(tuple)
    recoreded_pos = input.pos
    last_token_index = first_token_index
    string = token.dup
    while(count_and_match_tokens(string, index, counts, document_id, first_token_index, last_token_index)) do
      last_document_id, last_token_index, space, last_token = convert_tuple(input.shift)
      break if document_id != last_document_id
      string << " " if space == "1"
      string << last_token
    end
    input.pos = recoreded_pos
  end
end  

CSV.open(output_path,"w") do |output|
  counts.each do |tuple|
    output << tuple
  end
end
```

The `convert_tuple` function only makes basic conversion of the data (i.e. converts strings to numbers, etc.).

The `count_and_match_tokens` function counts the tokens and returns true, if the passed string argument is a prefix of a different string. I use a trie structure to effectively verify this condition.

**I am wondering how would look a solution that is written using functional style**. The problem I am facing is the fact that the matched sequence might span many tokens.

In Ruby (or in OO style in general) I can record the position where I started the matching (`recorded_pos = input.pos`) and "reset" the stream, when the sub-sequence matching is over (`input.pos = recorded_pos`). As a result a subsequent call to `each` will return the next token that is in the stream. So tokens inside already recognized sequences (the tokens that are processed inside the `while` loop) can also be first matching tokens in other sub-sequences.

I would be thankful for a solution in Elixir, but any other functional language would be OK as well.

**EDIT**

I have provided the definitions of `convert_tuple` and `count_and_match_tokens` as well as example input and output (the files are truncated, thus the counts does not directly correspond to the input file).

The index data structure that appears in the code is a Maris Trie (Melisa gem: https://github.com/wordtreefoundation/melisa/ )

Example input:

```
0   746 1   The
0   748 1   river
0   751 1   Bosna
0   754 1   (
0   763 0   )
0   765 1   (
0   766 0   Cyrillic
0   767 0   :
0   769 1   Босна
0   770 0   )
0   772 1   is
0   774 1   the
0   776 1   third
0   778 1   longest
0   781 1   river
0   784 1   in
0   787 1   Bosnia
0   789 1   and
0   791 1   Herzegovina
0   793 0   ,
0   795 1   and
0   797 1   is
0   799 1   considered
0   801 1   one
0   803 1   of
0   805 1   the
0   807 1   country
0   808 0   '
0   809 0   s
0   811 1   three
0   813 1   major
0   815 1   internal
0   817 1   rivers
```

Token sequence to be recognized:

```
Bosnia
Bosnia and Herzegovina
river
Herzegovina
```

Example output:

```
river,2
Bosnia,1
Bosnia and Herzegovina,1
Herzegovina,1
```

I hope this helps in understanding the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Have you tried writing any Elixir for this yet? And can you post some sample inputs and expected outputs? The code is hard to follow as it is not self contained (missing `convert_tuple`, `context`, and probably more things). (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have provided the necessary information. I hope the code is now easier to follow. Still the primary challenge is not with the details of the token manipulation, but with restarting the input stream each time several consequent tokens are consumed. I tried a solution in Elixier, but in fact I don't have any idea how to overcome the problem of stream restarting, thus my examples won't bring any value to the problem, I suppose.

Comment: Your example output contains information not provided in the input. Please provide example input and the intended output for that input only.

Comment: I have provided the input and output file that would match each other. I also provided a list of token sequences to be recognized.

Comment: I have expanded the dictionary with "Herzegovina", to illustrate a situation, when one of the expressions overlaps with another one, but they are not sharing prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

A runnable program (count_sequences.rb):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'set'

sequence_file, token_file = ARGV

sequences = Set.new

forest = File.readlines(sequence_file).each{|s| sequences << s.tap(&:chomp!)}.map!(&:split).each_with_object({}) do |words, root|
  words.reduce(root) do |parent, word|
    (parent[word] ||= [0, {}])[1]
  end
end
#=>  {
#      "Bosnia" => [0, {
#        "and" => [0, {
#          "Herzegovina" => [0, {}]
#        }]
#      }],
#      "river" => [0, {}]
#    }

File.open(token_file) do |f|
  current_node = forest

  f.each_line do |line|
    token = line.tap(&:chomp!).split[-1]
    spec = current_node[token] || forest[token]
    if spec
      spec[0] += 1
      current_node = spec[1]
    else
      current_node = forest
    end
  end
end
#=>  {
#      "Bosnia" => [1, {
#        "and" => [1, {
#          "Herzegovina" => [1, {}]
#        }]
#      }],
#      "river" => [2, {}]
#    }

def print_tree(node, sequences, parent = nil)
  node.each do |word, spec|
    sequence = [parent, word].compact.join(' ')
    puts "#{sequence},#{spec[0]}" if sequences.include? sequence
    print_tree(spec[1], sequences, sequence)
  end
end

print_tree(forest, sequences)
```

You can run it with

```
$ ruby count_sequences.rb /path/to/sequences.txt /path/to/tokens.txt
```

It outputs

```
Bosnia,1
Bosnia and Herzegovina,1
river,2
```

Comment: The solution is pretty nice, but does not match my solution exactly. The difference is in a situation when "Herzegovina" is in the dictionary as well. In such a case only "Bosnia and Herzegovina" would be matched (since the alternative current_node[token] || forest[token] would match only one node). If you can provide a solution that would work for this case as well I will grant a new bounty (100).